# get SHA1 fingerprint in android

Tags: android, sha1

I am using sketchware IDE on my android phone to make an app.
I want to enable google sign in so the user's daata on the app gets backed up to google and restore after a reinstall but it seems I need to get my app's SHA1 fingerprint and the only way i managed to find online is only valid if I use android studio as my IDE as it requires typing commands into CMD on windows or mac.

How can I get that fingerprint on my android phone instead of a PC?

Comment: What is the problem with using the commandline? The keystore file from which you get the SHA fingerprint is on the PC, so getting it from the phone won't be simpler than executing a command.

Comment: So should i just download a terminal app on my android and run the same commands as I would on PC?

Comment: Sorry if i sound like an idiot but it's because i am in this regards. This is all very new to me.

Comment: Why do you want to do it on your phone? What is the problem with doing it on PC which already has CMD or Terminal? You realize that those commands you found online don't need you to be using Android Studio IDE right?

Comment: My whole app and project is on my phone as I use an android IDE. There is no trace of android studio or my app on my PC

Comment: Well i thought it did require android studio, I have no clue what to do here actually, thats why I am here

Comment: Ah, I just saw the [Sketchware](http://sketchware.io/) site. I'm not sure how it works for you. You need to find the debug keystore file for getting the SHA, which is usually at a certain location on PC.

Comment: "on PC" is the keyword here and where my problem comes in. My whole app is built using my android.

Comment: seems you have to run those commands in your java directory which android studio uses so obviously cant run them on android hence my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see on their [First Time Publishing Guide](https://docs.sketchware.io/docs/publish-first-time.html), Sketchware handles signing for release APKs. This means you aren't the one who has the release keystore file. In the Firebase guide, they ask to skip providing a debug key.

I think it would be best if you contacted their support to get an understanding of how they handle APK signing. Integration of Google Sign In is quite common, so they should have a method in place.

Comment: Yeah i know how to sign the apk with sketchware but i get no info from it. It just signs it and thats thats. I get no information or data to use anywhere.

Comment: I contacted them, hopefully they reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Dev tools to get SHA-1 or SHA-256 , Download devtools from google play. Click on app info. Select your app and You'll get SHA-1 OR 256 . Devtools link below
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools